# Friendly with existing Rails 4 app: No change

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have an existing app with devise running. User and log in and out etc. Thought I would like to get `localhost:3000/users/15` changed to `localhost:3000/users/ruby-boy` so I have installed https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

I have ran `rails generate friendly_id` but when I ran `rails generate scaffold user name:string slug:string:uniq`, it say I already got a user.rb file so ok I've added: `rails g migration AddSlugToUser slug:string:uniq` and `rails g migration AddNameToUser name:string`. So I've added those two columns to my users table.

In my controllers I've replaced:

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

with:

```
User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Then ran this in console (`rails c`)

```
User.find_each(&:save)
```

But `User.find_each(&:save)` gave:

```
 (0.1ms)  commit transaction
 (0.0ms)  begin transaction
 => nil
```

I think I've followed the docs "eye for eye". Have I missed anything as the links wont change.

PS: I have edited the user.rb per website on github.

My user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      belongs_to :plan
      has_one :profile

      attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

      def save_with_payment
        if valid?
            customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
            self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
            save!
        end
      end
    end
```

Schema for users table:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
      t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
      t.string   "reset_password_token"
      t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
      t.datetime "remember_created_at"
      t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
      t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
      t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
      t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
      t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.integer  "plan_id"
      t.string   "stripe_customer_token"
      t.string   "slug"
      t.string   "name"
    end
```

Comment: What changes did you make to user model? And did you restart your server?

Comment: @neo I have added what's in my user model in post. Yes I have restarted.

Comment: Can you show me user attributes? Type User.attributes on the console

Comment: @neo I got this: `NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class`

Comment: Try attribute_names or post schema for users

Comment: @neo Updated. Have a look

Comment: Looks like you have everything you need in place, can you maybe run on console: User.last.slug and check if it exists

Comment: @neo Got this: `User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> nil`

Comment: So slug is nil, you need save the slugs

Comment: @neo Yes but this `User.find_each(&:save)` does nothing. See above what I got.

Comment: How many users do you have in your database?

Comment: @neo 17 lol. All are just test accounts. Do I need to delete all?

Comment: Ah ok, then create a new user and see if the slug exists for that user

Comment: @neo Tried that and nothing. My sign up form has email and password only then they can add their name etc from profile. Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes for sure, name doesn't exist and therefore slug is nil

Comment: @neo Yes I've added name to the signup and it works! But! Ive tried two same name. The last one friendly added some weird numbers at the end. Is there a way to check for uniq slug before adding to database?

Comment: Posted a solution, get rid of the duplicate name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `:name` to your sign up form and then validate for uniqueness in your User model

```
Class User
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

This way same name can't be created more than once and you'll avoid avoid weird slugs.